# Nginx Cache Control breaks working paths

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm following the html5boilerplate nginx setup for the most part, but everything keeps breaking when I include `expires.conf`.

HTML5BP for Nginx setup: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/tree/master/nginx

I've changed only a few very minor things which I'll put below. When in include `conf/expires.conf` however everything returns 404.

As a sidenote, I don't think it's just HTML5BP either.. i also followed [this guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/) and images also broke (under the heading for Nginx tip #5 static assets expire).

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           360d;
}
```

I'm using nginx on a server behind an EC2 elastic load balancer.

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/example.com;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # Specify a charset
    charset utf-8;

    # Custom 404 page
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    include conf/base.conf;
}
```

Comment: Can't find anything in your config that would cause that. How did you install nginx? What's in your nginx error log? You can display more info with the nginx error_log directive. Also you can built Nginx with --with-debug to show even more info. http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log

Comment: I have solved the issue. it was because i changed root to /var/www/html but i only specified root in my first location directive, so it was reading the default root in the binary when it couldnt find a defined root directive

Comment: I see. thanks for let us know. Most time you'd better put the root directive under server block, instead of the location block.